# Python Date Not Plotting Properly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I was wondering why the x-axis plots the dates wrong, it begins at the 05/02 when it should start at the 30/01, and I'm not sure where it is I went wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

cols = ['Time','Water Usage']
A = pd.read_csv("CSVFile", names=cols, parse_dates=[0])

plt.ylabel = "Time"
plt.xlabel = "Water Usage"
A.plot(x='Time',y='Water Usage')
plt.show()
```

The file is in the format

```
Date+Time  |  Usage

30/01/2018  | 50091

05/02/2018 |  50890
```

so ideally it should plot the 30/01 first followed by the 05/02, whereas currently its doing the opposite.

Comment: Untested, but shouldn't you add `dayfirst=True` to `pd.read_csv`?

Answer (score 2):

To make sure your program plots the x-values chronologically, you should convert the `Date+Time` column into a `datetime` object. I see you used `parse_dates` in your `read_csv`call, but the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) say it might not be 100% effective:

> If a column or index cannot be represented as an array of datetimes,
>   say because of an unparseable value or a mixture of timezones, the
>   column or index will be returned unaltered as an object data type. For
>   non-standard datetime parsing, use pd.to_datetime after pd.read_csv.
>   To parse an index or column with a mixture of timezones, specify
>   date_parser to be a partially-applied pandas.to_datetime() with
>   utc=True. See Parsing a CSV with mixed timezones for more.

So I would try the following ([to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)):

```
A['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(A['Time'])
A.sort_values(by='Time', inplace = True)
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just made a few changes to your code, mainly `pd.to_datetime` and it works fine:

```
cols = ['Time','Water Usage']
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='|')
df.columns = cols
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
plt.ylabel = "Time"
plt.xlabel = "Water Usage"
df.plot(x='Time',y='Water Usage')
plt.show()
```